# How to extend liquibase to execute some statement before each changeSet?

Tags: liquibase

I want to execute a specific statement before each changeSet, in the same transaction as the changeSet statements - this statement will set some transaction properties. The same statement should be executed for all changeSets and I don't want to repeat it in each changeSet definition. Ideally it will be able to react to some changeSet attributes like 'runInTransaction'. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

Liquibase has an extension system. Check out [this page](https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/display/CONTRIB/Overview) for an overview.

You could write your own "plugin" that adds this functionality. This is probably also the most flexible way to do it.

I doubt there is another way to do this without writing your own plugin - but I also don't know each and every part of liquibase...

Comment: Thanks Jens, I know about the extension system and I am willing to write my own plugin. However, none of the available extension points listed there seems to be appropriate to add the functionality I mentioned. Is it possible I missed something?